# Swift 3 - Show coordinates on map

Tags: swift, xcode, location, coordinates

I need help. I´m trying to show the coordinates I have on a map. I´m building up my project using the MVC model. But I do get an error that says that I cannot use CLLocationDegrees and I must use CLLocatiocoordinates2D instead. See my code down below.

EDIT: Updated my code so now does it work! Thanks for the answer!

Here is where I save the information (if you can say so?)

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

struct User {
let name: String
let position: CLLocationCoordinate2D

}
```

And here is my model:

```
import LBTAComponents
import CoreLocation

class HomeDataSource: Datasource {

let users: [User] = {
    let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.33233141, longitude: -122.0312186)

    let sebbeUser = User(name: "Sebbe", position: position)



    return [sebbeUser]

}()



override func cellClasses() -> [DatasourceCell.Type] {
    return [UserCell.self]
}

override func item(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> Any? {
    return users[indexPath.item]
}

override func numberOfItems(_ section: Int) -> Int {
    return users.count
}

}
```

And here is my cell, you can see that I have successfully printed out the name. You can see where I put a comment to see my problem.

```
import LBTAComponents
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class UserCell: DatasourceCell, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate  {


let distanceSpan: Double = 500


 override var datasourceItem: Any? {
    didSet {
        guard let user = datasourceItem as? User else { return }
        nameLabel.text = user.name
        MapView.setCenter(user.position, animated: false)


        }


   }

let nameLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
    return label

}()

let MapView: MKMapView = {
    let map = MKMapView()
    map.isZoomEnabled = false
    map.isScrollEnabled = false
    map.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    return map

}()
```

Comment: which line did you get the error?

Comment: Please show the exact code that gives the error.

Comment: I´ve updated the code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your latitude and longitude should be a type of

> CLLocationCoordinate2D

not

> CLLocationDegrees

.

Or else you can define only a one variable of type of CLLocationCoordinate2D.

like

```
var location = CLLocationCoordinate2D() 

location.coordinate.latitude = "-72.455412"
location.coordinate.longitude = "40.005165"
```

same way you can retrieve lat long. Just change your model variables. I guess it should be fine.

Other things looks fine in your code.

Comment: Yeah, I´ve figured it out but I need them to be CLLocationDegrees otherwise do I get an error in my model where I write the "name", "latitude" and "longitude".

Comment: Just changing your model lat,long into CLLocationCoordinate2D should not be any problem. Why you need CLLocationDegrees?

Comment: Okay, sorry I´m a bit new on this. But If I change in my model latitude and longitude to CLLCoordinate2D does the error disappear. But now do I get this error instead "Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected argument type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D'" in my `let sebbeUser = User(name: "Sebbe", latitude: 37.33233141, longitude: -122.0312186)`

Comment: try this way 

syntax : CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double Lat, longitude: Double Long)

Example :  CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 10.30, longitude: 44.34)

Comment: I´ve updated my model to CLCoordinates2D. But where should I write  CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double Lat, longitude: Double Long)?

Comment: Hi, I´ve update my code! And now does it work! Thanks anyway for the help!

Comment: Ok if my answer and comments helped you then please accept my answer and encourage me to write more answers :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put them into struct CLLocatiocoordinates2D.

[CLLocatiocoordinates2D](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationcoordinate2d)